# Can a figure 8 be an orbit of $dx /dt =f(x,y)$, $dy/ dt =g(x,y)$ where $f$ and $g$ have continuous partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can a figure 8 ever be an orbit of

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} & =f(x,y), \\[10pt]
\frac{dy}{dt} & =g(x,y)
\end{align}
where $f$ and $g$ have continuous partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Hint: Let $(x,y)$ be the self-intersection of the 8. Put $(x(0),y(0)) = (x,y)$ as initial conditions. What would the solutions be? Do we know that the solution is unique?

Comment: Don't know if you find this relevant, but it can be the so-called $\omega$-limit of an ode, i.e. the set of accumulation points of an orbit. Can develop if you think it is of interest.

Answer (score 10):

As was already stated by @chi, a figure 8 can't be an orbit because of the uniqueness of the solution at the self-intersection point; but it can be a composition of 3 trajectories: two parts of the figure and a self-intersection point. For instance, the phase portrait of the system
$$
\dot x=xy,\quad \dot y=y^2-x^4
$$
is as shown below:
[image]
The trajectories in the right and left half-planes are separate solutions tending to zero at $t\to\pm\infty$, so they do not intersect.

(This example is from the book *N. N. Bautin and E. A. Leontovich, “Methods and Ways of Qualitative Study of Dynamic Systems on a Plane,” In Russian, Nauka, Moscow, 1976.* )